# Отправка смс через gsm модем

Tags: php, sms

Появилась задача рассылки смс уведомлений. Данные для сообщения формируются через php, но вот с отправкой команд на модем возникла проблема.   Взятый [отсюда](http://www.php.su/forum/topic.php?forum=71&topic=11064&postid=1372774286#)
способ оказался слишком медленным и непостоянным (ожидание ответа слишком большое).  Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать отсылку команд модему через php?
  Решила воспользоваться советом ниже и настроить для этих целей kannel. Но смс все равно не отправляются. В bearerbox.log выводится следующий текст

> 2016-03-24 16:09:26 [35528] [0] INFO: Kannel bearerbox II version 1.4.3 starting
>   2016-03-24 16:09:26 [35528] [0] INFO: MAIN: Start-up done, entering mainloop
>   2016-03-24 16:09:26 [35528] [0] DEBUG: smsc_fake: start called
>   2016-03-24 16:09:26 [35528] [0] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: start called
>   2016-03-24 16:09:26 [35528] [9] DEBUG: wdp_to_wapboxes: destroying lists
>   2016-03-24 16:09:26 [35528] [9] DEBUG: Thread 9 (gw/bb_boxc.c:wdp_to_wapboxes) terminates.
>   2016-03-24 16:09:27 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: device opened
>   2016-03-24 16:09:27 [35528] [7] ERROR: AT2[APPM-smsc]: at_data_link: fail to set termios attribute
>   2016-03-24 16:09:27 [35528] [7] ERROR: System error 25: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>   2016-03-24 16:09:27 [35528] [7] INFO: AT2[APPM-smsc]: speed set to 115200
>   2016-03-24 16:09:27 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: --> ^M
>   2016-03-24 16:09:28 [35528] [5] INFO: Client connected from <127.0.0.1>
>   2016-03-24 16:09:28 [35528] [5] DEBUG: Started thread 12 (gw/bb_boxc.c:function)
>   2016-03-24 16:09:28 [35528] [12] DEBUG: Thread 12 (gw/bb_boxc.c:function) maps to pid 35528.
>   2016-03-24 16:09:28 [35528] [12] DEBUG: Started thread 13 (gw/bb_boxc.c:boxc_sender)
>   2016-03-24 16:09:28 [35528] [13] DEBUG: Thread 13 (gw/bb_boxc.c:boxc_sender) maps to pid 35528.
>   2016-03-24 16:09:28 [35528] [12] DEBUG: boxc_receiver: got boxc_id  from <127.0.0.1>
>   2016-03-24 16:09:29 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: --> AT^M
>   2016-03-24 16:09:29 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: <-- AT
>   2016-03-24 16:09:31 [35528] [10] INFO: Client connected from <127.0.0.1>
>   2016-03-24 16:09:31 [35528] [10] DEBUG: Started thread 14   (gw/bb_boxc.c:function)
>   2016-03-24 16:09:31 [35528] [14] DEBUG: Thread 14 (gw/bb_boxc.c:function) maps to pid 35528.
>   2016-03-24 16:09:31 [35528] [14] DEBUG: setting up systems for new wapbox
>   2016-03-24 16:09:31 [35528] [14] DEBUG: Started thread 15 (gw/bb_boxc.c:boxc_sender)
>   2016-03-24 16:09:31 [35528] [15] DEBUG: Thread 15 (gw/bb_boxc.c:boxc_sender) maps to pid 35528.
>   2016-03-24 16:09:31 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: <-- OK
>   2016-03-24 16:09:31 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: --> AT&F^M
>   2016-03-24 16:09:35 [35528] [7] ERROR: AT2[APPM-smsc]: Couldn't connect (retrying in 10 seconds).
>   2016-03-24 16:09:45 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: detecting modem type
>   2016-03-24 16:09:45 [35528] [7] INFO: AT2[APPM-smsc]: opening device
>   2016-03-24 16:09:45 [35528] [7] WARNING: AT2[APPM-smsc]: trying to open device with not closed device!!! Please report!!!
>   2016-03-24 16:09:45 [35528] [7] INFO: AT2[APPM-smsc]: Closing device
>   2016-03-24 16:09:45 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: device opened. Telnet mode = 0
>   2016-03-24 16:09:45 [35528] [7] ERROR: AT2[APPM-smsc]: at_data_link: fail to set termios attribute
>   2016-03-24 16:09:45 [35528] [7] ERROR: System error 25: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>   2016-03-24 16:09:46 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: device opened
>   2016-03-24 16:09:46 [35528] [7] ERROR: AT2[APPM-smsc]: at_data_link: fail to set termios attribute
>   2016-03-24 16:09:46 [35528] [7] ERROR: System error 25: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>   2016-03-24 16:09:46 [35528] [7] INFO: AT2[APPM-smsc]: speed set to 115200
>   2016-03-24 16:09:46 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: --> ^M
>   2016-03-24 16:09:48 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: --> AT^M
>   2016-03-24 16:09:48 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: <-- AT
>       2016-03-24 16:09:50 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: <-- OK
>       2016-03-24 16:09:50 [35528] [7] DEBUG: AT2[APPM-smsc]: --> AT&F^M

Настройки kannel.conf получились такими:

> group = core
>   admin-port = 13000
>   smsbox-port = 13001
>   wapbox-port = 13002
>   admin-password = 1
>   dlr-storage= internal
>
> group = smsc
>   smsc = at
>   smsc-id = APPM-smsc
>   modemtype = auto
>   device = com1
>   connect-allow-ip = 127.0.0.1
>   speed = 115200
>   sim-buffering = true
>   sms-center = +7000000000
>
> group = smsbox
>   bearerbox-host = localhost
>   smsbox-id = My-smsbox
>   sendsms-port = 13013
>   global-sender = 13013
>
> group = wapbox
>   bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
>   syslog-level = none
>
> group = sendsms-user
>   username = tester
>   password = foobar
>
> group = sms-service
>   keyword = default
>   text = "You asked nothing and I did it!"
>   catch-all = true
>
> group = sms-service
>   keyword = default
>   text = "No service specified"
>
> group  = modems
>   id = SIEMENS MC35i
>   name = "Siemens_MC35i"
>   detect-string = "SIEMENS"
>   detect-string2 = "MC35i"
>   init-string = "AT+CMEE=2;+CNMI=3,1,0,0,0"
>   enable-hwhs = "AT\Q3"
>   need-sleep = true
>   message-storage = SMS

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, что не так?

Comment: слишком медленный - это несколько штук в секунду?

Comment: медленный- это чтобы получить подтверждение что порт открыт, уходит 1 минута

Comment: это действительно медленно. Скорее всего тратиться время на согласование скоростей/параметров. Берите [portmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/portmon.aspx) и смотрите, что там твориться.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/). Он будет отвечать за взаимодействие с модемом и отправку SMS, а вы будете из PHP выполнять простой http GET запрос.

Быстро, надежно, универсально.

Comment: а есть подобная программка для windows 7?

Comment: Есть сборка https://www.ddj.co.za/kannel-for-windows но я ее не пробовал. Проще поднять виртуалку и пробросить туда USB.

Comment: решила попробовать эту сборку) Не подскажите, какой в настройках указывать тип модема(modemtype)? У меня  GSM modem Cinterion MC52i.

Comment: С этой моделю я не работал. Можно попробовать modem-type = generic Но далеко не факт что заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Не, ну если вы не ровно дышите к костылям, то можно рискнуть нагородить, и через `exec()` отдавать команды на ADB, который будет управлять модемом.